# How to validate Email (only containing, numbers, letters, asterisk, at, underscore, point)

Tags: java

I need to validate Emails for an exercise. The Email is only allowed to contain:

- 0-9
- a-z
- A-Z
- @
- Asterisk
- Underscore
- Point

if the email doesnt contain @ but ends with asterisk, it should extend a String to make it a E-Mail. I tried using ASCII Code but that is just way to much. Also I saw regex is a thing but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: Try to use google, it has all the answers. [Here is your answer](https://mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using Regex is a convenient solution for this. It is very easy to implement. You can find some regex email validator patterns in a google search.

Here is a sample regex pattern that validate an email : ^(.+)@(.+)$

```
    //1st way  
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.+)@(.+)$");//. represents single character  
Matcher m = p.matcher("sapmle@sample.com");  
boolean b = m.matches();  // returns true
  
//2nd way  
boolean b2=Pattern.compile("^(.+)@(.+)$").matcher("[text you want to validate]").matches();  
  
//3rd way  
boolean b3 = Pattern.matches("^(.+)@(.+)$", "[text you want to validate]");
```